# Extract value of a dynamic data through http using cURL and C API

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract the RSSI value of a Wifi access point in my network. The only solution available is to connect it using its ip adress and try to read the value in its status page.
During my research I found the cURL library and I write a some code to connect and extract the status page. But I only have the code of the page and not the value that I need to get.

So, I need your help to find the right way to extract the value of the data.

My configuration: Linux Ubuntu for now, but SW will be used in a raspberry like interface, Eclipse CDT.

The code that I writed:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:password");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.5.179");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
```

The data that I need to read (wlan1_signal):

```
Signal Strength:</td>

                                            <td >

                                                <div class="style2">

                                                    &nbsp;<span id="wlan1_signal">None</span>&nbsp;</div>

                                            </td>
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: 
On the html code of the page, I found that a script is executed to generate the dynamics values:

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/status.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In this script (http://192.168.5.179/en/js/status.js), I found the code line that generate the RSSI value:

```
remote_call("get_wifi_info", wlan_devs[index].cdev, 
                function(data){ ...
$("#wlan"+index+"_signal").html(get_regex(data, /Link Quality=(\S+)/));
...
```

But my issue remain the same: how to read the value generated??

Comment: Why not use a bash script? You're already in html scraping, I doubt you require the performance of a native application. A curl call piped into a grep with a capturing group regex should give you what you want as a one-liner.

Comment: I'm trying to find another solution because this RSSI value will be used for a positioning task. The value will be read and send in a loop until the end of the positionning. But thank you for your idea, I will use it if nobody can help me to find the solution.

Comment: If you still want to deal with libcurl, this is what you need I believe (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html). From this callback, you should be able to parse the content with strtok and find what you need. Parsing HTML with strtok is not for the faint-hearted though.

Comment: Not especialy with libcurl, but for now that's the only solution that I found to do it avoiding a "system(...)" function.

Comment: Have you tested the callback solution?

Comment: I tryed but i did not success:  I don't understand why, but it does't read the full content of the page. So I don't have the data that I need...

Comment: @sturcotte06 Can you explain to me the first solution that you have  talked in the first post please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to retrieve the value, regardless of performance, you could use a bash command.

```
curl -s -u admin:password "http://192.168.5.179" | grep -Po '(?<=<span id="wlan1_signal">)[^<]+'
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I use it I obtain only the progress bar. I found and try this shell command this morning but the result if the same...                   $(curl -u admin:password 192.168.5.179 | grep 'wlan1_signal' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $10}')

Comment: You need the add the -s flag (for silent). I've edited my answer. Given the same html output you gave in your question, the grep works.

Comment: Thanks. When I try it in a terminal, nothing happend. And I tryed it in my C api with an int to store the result, but my  variable remain to "0".             
`system ("uiRSSILevel = curl -s -u admin:password 'http://192.168.5.179' | grep -Po '(?<=<span id=wlan1_signal>)[^<]+' ");`

Comment: Well have you tried to debug it? If you only invoke curl, what is the output in the console? Also, I'm pretty sure pipes are a bash thing, you can't use them in `system()`.

Comment: First I tryed it in the shell and I had only the progress bar as "answer", so I tryed with some option like --silent  and -v to try to have more information, but I did no success. When I added -s or --silent I have nothing (only the possibility to enter a new command). That why I tyed to do it with the system() instruction in my api.

Comment: Are you sure? When I do `curl -s http://www.google.com`, I get the html page printed in the console, without any progress bar or headers. Are you sure you're not getting a 3xx, 4xx or 5xx response? Also, if I do `echo "<your html>" | grep -Po "(?<=<span id=wlan1_signal>)[^<]+"`, I have `None` printed in the console, which is the value you seek.

Comment: But , I don't know, but I think that I will have the text  wlan1_signal and not the value of the variable, aren't I?

Comment: Nope, I get `None` printed, which is the value of the html tag.

Comment: Yes sure, with `curl -s http://www.google.com` I get 7 lines of HTML. Then, I tryed `curl --silent -u  admin:password "http://192.168.5.179"` and I get the html page that says that: `This document has moved to a new <a href="http://192.168.5.179/en/status.html">location</a>.
  Please update your documents to reflect the new location.`. So I tryed this: `curl --silent -u  admin:password "http://192.168.5.179/en/status.html"`. And I get the complete html page,

Comment: but, with the complete command : `curl --silent -u  admin:password "http://192.168.5.179/en/status.html" | grep -Po "(?<=<span id=wlan1_signal>)[^<]+"`, I get nothing!!

Comment: Dude, you need to be a little bit more resourceful. the grep misses the double quotes because I copied the thing too fast. Try `grep -Po '(?<=<span id="wlan1_signal">)[^<]+'` If you're gonna use linux, you need to understand what you're doing and be able to adapt to your specific problem.

Comment: I'm using Linux since 2 month, so it's relatively new for me. I have no training on it so I'm learning of my mistakes! I have already tryed to add " " around wlan_signal, but I didn't know for ' ' for the grep. Thank you for your help, now I get the "None". So we going ahead!!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's what you wanted =)

Comment: It help me a lot, it's not exactly what I need because I get "none" and not the value expected (I mean, When I'm checking this page in a web explorer, the None is replaced by the RSSI value computed by a script), but I learnt so many thing and I'm on a good way!